# Variable storing only one value, python

Tags: python, pandas

so while trying to make some updates at local database, having issues the loop is just getting last row values.

- The variables `id_value  and  cost_value` is getting only the last row value
- How to get all the values? to be able to update old research records

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['09999900795', '00009991136', '000094801299', '000099900300', '0075210657'],
    'Cost': ['157.05974458228403', '80.637745302714', '7', '13', '65.5495495']
})
```

My code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    id_value = [row['id']]
    cost_value = [row['Cost']]

    # this row updates the data, however the variables is getting only the last value 
    #table.update().where(table.c.id== id_value).values(Cost=cost_value)


print(id_value)
print(cost_value)

out[12]: 
       ['0075210657']
       ['65.5495495']
```

Desired output:

```
       ['09999900795', '00009991136', '000094801299', '000099900300', '0075210657']
       ['157.05974458228403', '80.637745302714', '7', '13', '65.5495495']
```

Comment: if you want to print the variables as they get assigned, you need to move them into the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python `for` loops will update the value of `id_value` and `cost_value` on every iteration. This is why you are only seeing the last value in the row.

If what you want is a Python list of every value in that column, you can do that more efficiently than looping by using `df['id'].tolist()`.

Timing the difference of these with your (small) example dataset:

```py
import timeit

setup_string = '''
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['09999900795', '00009991136', '000094801299', '000099900300', '0075210657'],
    'Cost': ['157.05974458228403', '80.637745302714', '7', '13', '65.5495495']
})
'''

code_string1 = '''
id_values = [] 
cost_values = [] 
for _, row in df.iterrows(): 
    id_values.append(row['id']) 
    cost_values.append(row['Cost'])
'''

code_string2 = '''
id_values = df['id'].tolist() 
cost_values = df['Cost'].tolist()
'''

timeit.timeit(code_string1, setup_string, number=10000)
timeit.timeit(code_string2, setup_string, number=10000)
```

The first, iterative example gives `5.5589933570008725` seconds on my machine, while the second example gives `0.2375467009987915` seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *append* values to each list; you are simply defining a new list in each iteration.

```
id_values = []
cost_values = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    id_values.append(row['id'])
    cost_values.append(row['Cost'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id': ['09999900795', '00009991136', '000094801299', '000099900300', '0075210657'],
'Cost': ['157.05974458228403', '80.637745302714', '7', '13', '65.5495495']
```

})

```
id_value=df['id'].tolist()
cost_value=df['Cost'].tolist()
```